# Evo/lution AIS crashing when I run the installer

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux, openbox

I'm trying to install Arch using the Evo/lution installer. After I boot into the Evo/Lution system, I am presented with a desktop. I connect to wifi, and am able to load webpages. I right click on the desktop and am presented with a menu with the options of "Lution-AIS installer, On-line Guide, Hardware Information, Terminal, Restart/Shutdown".

I click Lution-AIS installer and I am presented with a screen that says "Lution-AIS Initialisation Script 1.1". It says please wait, and I wait. It then presents me with a screen that says "Installer Version". I click on the stable version, and it pops up with another terminal, which flashes that it is connected to Github, then closes and does nothing. I am able to reproduce the bug with the development version as well. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: turns out my system time is off, causing ssl certs to be invalid. I will reset the system time and see if that corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to change my clock from Jan 04, 1980 to the current date. My clock was making the SSL certs invalid. I used ntpdate to update the time. When I ran the installer again, all checks passed.